# What library should I use to connect an iPhone app to a Ruby on Rails server?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails

I'm starting a new iPhone project and I want to get started off on the right foot. It's going to be talking to a Ruby on Rails server for some basic CRUD operations. I'd like to avoid dealing with URLs, HTTP requests and responses, and such. Are there any libraries out there that make this easier?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like http://iphoneonrails.com makes things pretty simple. You create custom classes in Objective-C that mirror your Ruby classes. You automatically get the following methods for CRUD:

```
//Create
Dog *dog = [[[Dog alloc] init] autorelease];
dog.name = @"Fido";
[dog saveRemote];

//Read
NSArray *dogs = [Dog findAllRemote];
dog = [Dog findRemote:dog.dogId];

//Update
dog.name = @"Fido Jones";
[dog updateRemote];

//Delete
[dog destroyRemote];
```

You can also fairly easily add methods to your Objective-C classes to call non-CRUD methods in your Ruby classes.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't work well with Three20. Someone's working on it, but it doesn't look ready yet: http://github.com/searls/TTResource.

Answer (score 1):

I use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit).  It works very well.

From the RestKit GitHub Wiki:

> RestKit is a framework for iOS and Mac OS X providing network access to RESTful HTTP web services, a powerful object mapping engine, and integration with Apple's Core Data framework for local persistence of objects existing in a remote backend system.

RestKit lets you easily implement Object Mapping:

> RestKit's key differentiating feature from other HTTP toolkits in the iOS space is the tightly integrated support for object mapping. Object mapping is the process of taking a representation of data in one format and transforming it into another form. This mechanism is used extensively within RestKit to streamline the serialization and deserialization of resources exchanged with a remote backend application server via HTTP. Object mapping operations are performed when you load a remote resource via an instance of RKObjectManager and when a local object is sent to the backend for processing.

The Object Mapping feature allow you to sync your iOS models with your server models relatively easily.

RestKit is constantly being improved, and it has a lot of support from the iOS developer community.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sure.  I just added some more info.